# How to verify the disabled dates from datepicker in selenium IDE?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

We are using javascript and the datepicker also contain the `aria-disable=ture/false`. Can anyone help me how to test either the `aria-disabled=ture or false` based on the condition. Please help me how to resolve this problem in **selenium IDE** not in selenium Web driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have to use the store attribute command :**

[image]

store attribute command finds the element using CSS locator and gets the attribute value mentioned after the '@' symbol. Then the value is stored to the specified variable in the value field.

For instance:

For getting the data-questionid for the below element:

```
<div class="question" data-questionid="42375" id="question">
```

we set target for store attribute as :

```
css=div#question@data-questionid
```

here,

```
div#question
```

is the css locator for a tag with div and id as question, the attribute that we need is mentioned after the @ symbol. In this case we needed `data-questionid`. In your case it will be `aria-disabled`

**To validate this you can use the assert command:**

The assert command expects the variable that contains an actual result as the target, and the expected value in the Value field

Remember, that for all other commands we mention the variable as ${variablename} but for assert we need to use it as variablename

Comment: thank you so much. It works for me

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign